What Java library is recommended for making android apps with basic signal interaction?
I am trying to create an app that networks by sending media through Signal's pre-existing network.
It must:

Be a Java library
Work alongside a preinstalled signal app
Have good documentation or preferably, tutorials
Support sending media and messages  to both individuals and groups using simple, high-level function calls
Not be deprecated

Optional:

Less important features such as registration or calling

So far, I have come across libsignal-service-java, but it is deprecated and does not have extensive documentation as far as I've found.
